# System of equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am a beginner in Latex and I would like to know how I can write this system of equations

[image]

But I don't know how.

I have tried this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{equation}
\centering
\left\{\begin{split}
\mfrac{k_{i\omega}}{k_{p\omega}} &=2\pi \times 10 \\
|\mfrac{(k_{p\omega}s + k_{i\omega})}{s}.\mfrac{1}{(T s + 1)}| &= 1 \\ 
\end{split}\right.
 \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

But I couldn't get the absolute value symbol as shown in the figure above and also I couldn't display the `s=jw` under the absolute value symbol and also the equations aren't aligned

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A solution using the `cases` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      k_{i\omega}/k_{p\omega}=2\pi\times 10\\
      \left\lvert\frac{k_{p\omega}s+k_{i\omega}}{s}\cdot\frac{1}{Ts+1}\right\rvert_{S=\mathrm{j}\cdot2\pi}=1
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I do not prefer using `cases` if there are no cases semantically speaking (WYSIWYM).

Comment: @ivankokan that's why I've added the cleaner `array` approach.

Answer (score 13):

A solution using `array` (no packages needed):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    k_{i\omega}/k_{p\omega}=2\pi\times 10\\
    \left|
      \frac{k_{p\omega}s+k_{i\omega}}{s}\cdot\frac{1}{Ts+1}
    \right|_{S=\mathrm{j}\cdot2\pi}=1
  \end{array}\right.\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & k_{i\omega} / k_{p\omega} = 2\pi \times 10 \\
      & {\left|
        \frac{k_{p\omega}s + k_{i\omega}}{s} \cdot \frac{1}{Ts + 1}
      \right|}_{s = j \cdot 2\pi} = 1
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, I want the equations to aligned on the left not based on the equal operator?

Comment: I want the first equation to be on the left too

Comment: Edited. In general, use the `&` to specify the place of alignment.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to do it, with the `dcases` and `spreadlines` environments, from `mathtools`. The latter package lets you define additional vertical spacing between rows of a multiline equation, which is necessary here, due to the fractions in each line.

I added another solution with the `empheq` package.

Unrelated: preferably load `nccmath` *before* `mathtools`, as there might be problems with the `\intertext` command. Also, I defined an `\abs` command for the absolute value with the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools` to have the vertical lines adjusted to their contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq} %% loads mathtools, which loads amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{1ex}
\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
\mfrac{k_{i\omega}}{k_{p\omega}} =2\pi \times 10 \\
\abs*{\mfrac{(k_{p\omega}s + k_{i\omega})}{s}\cdot \mfrac{1}{(T s + 1)}}= 1
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{spreadlines}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
     & \mfrac{k_{i\omega}}{k_{p\omega}} =2\pi \times 10 \\
     & \abs*{\mfrac{(k_{p\omega}s + k_{i\omega})}{s}\cdot \mfrac{1}{(T s + 1)}}= 1
    \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of \abs*{stuff} compared with \abs{stuff}?

Comment: It adds a pair of implicit `\left ... \right`.  Another solution  would be, say, `\abs[\bigg]{stuff}`, which adds a pair of implicit `\biggl ... \biggr`.

Answer (score 3):

For those like me that came here just to know how to represent a system with two lines of equations and don't care about the rest:

---

```latex
\[
A =
\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{l}
        a &\\
        b
    \end{array} 
\right.
\]
```

[image]

(screenshot taken from Obsidian markdown editor)

---

#### Simple explanation

- You put your equations inside `\begin{array}{l} \end{array}`, the `l` mean align left.
- You separate every element of the array with `&` and use `\\` to change line and put them on different lines.
- `\left\{` creates the curly brace on the left and `\right.` means there's no visible delimiter on the right.
- You can add as many lines as you want, likes this:

```latex
\[
A =
\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{l}
        a &\\
        b &\\
        c &\\
        d
    \end{array} 
\right.
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I respectfully disagree. It adds a lot because it shows only the basic code that someone trying to represent a system needs with a basic explanation without any of the extra confusing code that will just scare anyone that is not a latex specialist and doesn't have the time to or patience to analyse the entire code of other answers. Any student that needs this information for a project and is already overwhelmed by the lack of time they have will be thankful to see it simplified.

Comment: Completely agree, with the above, sometimes is just a simple equation or something fast without the need to use anything else

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a customized environment in mathematical expression or equation in the preamble

```
\newenvironment{system}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
```

And in the text for example

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{system}
equation 1  \\
equation 2 
\end{system}
\end{equation}
```

This code works but was suggested to me by a friend during I was writing my master's thesis

Comment: This is essentially Skillmon's answer, wrapped in a custom environment.

Comment: In fact is more clean in the text if there are more systems of equations. Now is less obscure the compact definition in the preample. But thanks to this community for having improved my knowledge. I'm new and tell me if my answer is useless. My friend was and is still a guru for me in using LaTex...

Answer (score 1):

I added my humble proposal using an `array` for my MWE. The output is very similar to the previous answers. The screenshot is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
 k_{i\omega}/k_{p\omega}=2\pi\times 10 &\\
\Bigl|\frac{k_{p\omega}s + k_{i\omega}}{s}\cdot\frac{1}{Ts+1}
\Bigr|_{S=\mathrm{j}\cdot 2\pi}=1
\end{array} \right.$ 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

This uses the `amsmath` package due to the use of `\substack`. This avoids any `align, aligned, gather, array, ...` environments but I had to pay the price of aligning manually.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\Large\left\{\substack{\hspace{-2.1cm}\,k_{i\omega}/k_{p\omega}\,=\,2\pi\,\times\, 10\vspace{0.2cm}\\\,\left|\frac{k_{p\omega}s\,+\,k_{i\omega}}{s}\,\cdot\,\frac{1}{Ts\,+\,1}\right|_{s\,=\,{\rm j}\,\cdot\,2\pi}\,=\,1}\right.$$
\end{document}
```

[image]